# multiple submit buttons and hidden values in html form

Tags: html, forms, hidden-field

I have a form with two submit buttons and both submit buttons have a different name so I can differentiate which button was clicked. The problem are the hidden values. For `button1`, I would like to send `value=1`, for `button2`, I would like to send `value=2` in a hidden value. But when `button1` was clicked, then hidden value=2 goes into the POST instead of value=1.

```
<form action="destination.php" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="car" value="1">
   <button type="submit" name="button1" value="button1">Button 1</button>

   <input type="hidden" name="car" value="2">
   <button type="submit" name="button2" value="button 2>Button 2</button>
</form>
```

How can I send hidden value=1 when `button1` was clicked and hidden value=2 when `button2` was clicked? 
Do I have to create a form for each submit button and the associated hidden values or is there a different way to pass hidden values with only one form?

Comment: You add an event handler to the button click and set the value of your hidden input based on whatever condition you need.

Comment: I noticed that there is a syntax error in your second button.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply name your inputs differently like car1 and car2 and then listen for each. or even set a different ID to each input and listen for the ID.

Answer (score 0):

On `destination.php` you could do:

```php
if (isset($_POST['button1']) {
   $car = 1;
} else if (isset($_POST['button2']) {
   $car = 2;
}
```

And then you could get rid of the hidden input elements.